# Storing an ABRecordRef into Core Data Object

Tags: ios, ipad, core-data, addressbook, abaddressbook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IPhone SDK - How to serialize ABRecord?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204712/iphone-sdk-how-to-serialize-abrecord)

I am writing an iPad app that uses the address book APIs to present the standard address book UI (ABNewPersonViewController) to enter contact info.  I do not want these records to be stored in the standard address book but rather, in the app's database.  Can I convert a ABRecordRef object directly to an NSData object and store it with core data?  If so, how exactly would I do that?  Thanks!!!

Comment: I think this is a duplicate question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204712/iphone-sdk-how-to-serialize-abrecord](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204712/iphone-sdk-how-to-serialize-abrecord)