# How to convert ABRecordRef to NSData and NSData to ABRecordRef?

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, abrecordref

I am trying to convert `ABRecordRef` to `NSdata`, but I am not sure how to achieve it. I want to save `ABRecordRef` to **sqlite** database and then after some time to add the same `ABRecordRef` to address book. I have tried this, but I am not sure whether it is the right way or not

```
 NSData *d = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:ref length:sizeof(ref)];
```

or something like this

```
NSData *data= (NSData *) ref;
```

it would be great if you showed me some way to convert it to `NSdata` and then back to `ABRecordRef`.

And is there any way I can store `NSdata` or directly `ABRecordRef` to **sqlite** database?

Answer (score 0):

I think the same question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204712/iphone-sdk-how-to-serialize-abrecord).

Basically, what you are trying to do won't work because you are mixing plain C types with Objective-C types. Instead, what you could do is copy all the relevant properties of the `ABRecord` to an `NSDictionary` (or your own custom `NSObject`) and then serialize/deserialize *that* instead.